# Is therre any crystal coding style to prevent nil error in compiling

Tags: crystal-reports, amber-framework

I am a newbie of crystal and amber framework, and when I try to rewrite a rails app with db to amber, I encountered a lot of compile error complained about nil matching, even sometime it is clearly not nil I think, such as

```
doc = Document.first("where id = ?",params[:id])
if doc.title.nil?
  title = ""
else
  title = doc.title
end
```

I must write as such

```
doc = Document.first("where id = ?",params[:id])
title = ""
if doc
  if doc.title.nil?
    title = ""
  else
    title = doc.title.not_nil!
  end
end
```

I think maybe it is because of my code style.

So is there some good code style document for crystal or
good practices?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to crystal too however, you can remove the nested if block with a guard clause.

`return unless doc`

Also, you can set a default value with granite. So where you put `title = ""` can be removed if the default value is an empty string. With that in mind, you new code would be:

```
doc = Document.first("where id = ?",params[:id])
return unless doc
title = doc.title
```